# Using setattr() and getattr() in Python descriptors

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, setattr, python-descriptors

While trying to create descriptors a few different ways I noticed some strange behavior that I'm trying to understand. Below are the three different ways I have gone about creating descriptors:

```
>>> class NumericValueOne():
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
...         return obj.__dict__.get(self.name) or 0
...     def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
...         obj.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

```
>>> class NumericValueTwo():
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         self.internal_name = '_' + self.name
...     def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
...         return getattr(obj, self.internal_name, 0)
...     def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
...         setattr(obj, self.internal_name, value)
```

```
>>> class NumericValueThree():
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
...         return getattr(obj, self.name, 0)
...     def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
...         setattr(obj, self.name, value)
```

I then use them in the `Foo` classes, like below:

```
>>> class FooOne():
...     number = NumericValueOne("number")

>>> class FooTwo():
...     number = NumericValueTwo("number")

>>> class FooThree():
...     number = NumericValueThree("number")

my_foo_object_one = FooOne()
my_foo_object_two = FooTwo()
my_foo_object_three = FooThree()

my_foo_object_one.number = 3
my_foo_object_two.number = 3
my_foo_object_three.number = 3
```

While `FooOne` and `FooTwo` work as expected when both setting & getting values. `FooThree` throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __set__
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __set__
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __set__
  [Previous line repeated 497 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

It looks like `setattr()` is calling the `__set__()` method? But why should it be doing that if `setattr()` is modifying the `obj` `__dict__`? And why does this work if we use `internal_name`?

Why is that we NEED to use a private variable in order to use the built-in `getattr()` and `setattr()` methods correctly? Also, how is this different from just directly modifying the `obj` `__dict__` like in `NumericValueOne`?

Comment: "setattr" and "getattr" respect descriptors and call them if present, this is a design decision of Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why should it be doing that if `setattr()` is modifying the `obj` `__dict__`?

`setattr` *doesn't* just modify the `__dict__`. It sets attributes, exactly like `x.y = z` would, and for the attribute you're trying to set, "set this attribute" means "call the setter you're already in". Hence, infinite recursion.

> And why does this work if we use `internal_name`?

That name doesn't correspond to a property, so it just gets a `__dict__` entry.